# Find function $G$ based on the result of its 2D derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to find function $G$ where
$$
\nabla G = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}G  \\ 
                          \frac{\partial }{\partial y}G          
           \end{bmatrix} = 
           \begin{bmatrix}x+y \\
            x-y 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I know that $G$ has to be a function based on $x$ and $y$. First I tried to integrate the two functions and I got $x^2/2 + x y$ and $-x y + y^2/2$ respectively. This did not allow me to make a suitable value for $G$. What would such an expression be?

Comment: You can transform this into $G_x+G_y=2x+0y$ by treating these like parametric equations and integrating to get $G =c(y-x)+x^2$ where c is a constant.

Comment: Hi @TymaGaidash, I don't think I understand what you are saying in this comment.

Comment: If $\frac{d}{dx} G=G_x=x+y, \frac{d}{dy}G =G_y=x-y$, then $G_x+G_y=x+y+x-y=2x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f(x,y) =x^2/2+xy-y^2/2$

$\partial_xf=\partial_x(x^2/2)+\partial_x(xy)+\partial_x(-y^2/2)= x+y+0$

$\partial_yf=\partial_y(x^2)+\partial_y(xy)+\partial_y(-y^2/2)=0+x-y$.

Comment: Thank you @Tsemo Aristide, this helps a lot :D